# Как выделить участки с большими значениями дБ?

Tags: python, аудио, scipy

Считываю аудио записи с помощью scipy.io.waw
Отрисовав данные из wav по времени получается следующая картина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

по оси х - время , по у - значения данных из wav
Возникла такая проблема - не получается выделить куски времени тех фрагментов, которые обведены красным цветом ( промежутки времени, где амплитуда больше остальной по времени)
никак не могу придумать программную реализацию
проблема из за того, что в приближении график выглядит следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно решить данную задачу оптимальным способом?

Comment: Не знаю есть ли готовые функции, но напрашивается некое "окошко", которым надо идти по оси `x` и брать максимум `y` по "окну". Главное, размер нужный у "окна" подобрать".

Comment: вроде в сайпай был метод `scipy.signal.find_peaks()`.

Comment: Спасибо, это было то , что нужно!

Comment: я помню в юности на с++ эти пики искал.... так элементарно же. берешь по модулю и скользящее среднее)